# SSIS- Derived column using Case Statement

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a derived column using a case statement but having trouble doing so.
I am new to SSIS so a bit confused how to do it.

In SQL terms the statement i want to use is as below:

```
CASE WHEN CYCLE not like '%Budget%' THEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '1 ' + STUFF(cycle, 4, 1, '20'), 109) ELSE NULL END as Month_Cycle_Start
```

I having been trying the following in SSIS but no luck with it.

```
[Cycle] not like '%Budget%' ? TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '1 ' + STUFF([Cycle] , 4, 1, '20'), 109): ELSE NULL
```

Comment: Since you already figured out you can use the ternary operator, I guess the thing you are missing is the `not like` expression part. You should get this covered by the `FINDSTRING` function. A more "SSISish" way would probably be to create a *Conditional Split* but this would likely come with a considerable performance penalty.

Comment: I have made a few updates but still having issue. Im guessing its the STUFF logic which is putting it off. Does SSIS have anythign similar. [Cycle] FINDSTRING '%Budget%' ? TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '1 ' + STUFF([Cycle], 4, 1, '20'), 109) :  NULL(DT_DATE)

Comment: If there aren't too many `[Cycle]` variants, I'd work around the dynamic `STUFF([Cycle] ...)` and go the *Conditional Split* path splitting by `[Cycle]`.